# Why am i getting an "undeclared identifier" error in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, class, undeclared-identifier

So we're assigned at school to create a class time. They want us to seperate the class with a time.h header file, a time.cpp cpp file and a main.cpp cpp file. I've got the following code, but for some reason I keep getting an "undeclared identifier" error. All 3 files are included in my project right now.

Here is the code:

time.h

```
class time
{
private:
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
public:
    time();
    time(int sec);
    time(int h, int min, int sec);
    int getTime();
    void setHours(int h);
    void setMinutes(int min);
    void setSeconds(int sec);
    bool equals(time t);
    void addTime(time t);
    void printTime();
    void normalize();

};
```

time.cpp

```
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

time::time()
{}
time::time(int sec)
{}
time::time(int h, int min, int sec)
{}
int time::getTime()
{
    return (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
}
void time::setHours(int h)
{
    hours = h;
}
void time::setMinutes(int min)
{
    minutes = min;
}
void time::setSeconds(int sec)
{
    seconds = sec;
}
bool time::equals(time t)
{
    if (hours == t.hours && minutes == t.minutes && seconds == t.seconds)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
void time::addTime(time t)
{
    hours += t.hours;
    minutes += t.minutes;
    seconds += t.seconds;
}
void time::printTime()
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hours
        << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << minutes
        << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << seconds;
}
void time::normalize()
{
    seconds %= 60;
    minutes = minutes + (seconds / 60);
    hours = hours + (minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes % 60;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time time1;
    int seconds1;
    cout << "Enter the amount of seconds: ";
    cin >> seconds1;
    time time2(seconds1);
    int hours2, minutes2, seconds2;
    cout << "Enter the amount of hours: ";
    cin >> hours2;
    cout << "Enter the amount of muinutes: ";
    cin >> minutes2;
    cout << "Enter the amount of seconds: ";
    cin >> seconds2;
    time time3(hours2, minutes2, seconds2);
    time1.equals(time2);

}
```

Comment: Include the full error message please.

Comment: how do you compile it ?

Comment: for which identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the given code I receive a whole raft of error messages, the most telling being

> ```
> warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'time'
>      time time1;
>           ^
> ```

This leads to `time1` being reported as not declared later because it isn't.

The Standard library contains a header time.h and a function `time.` To ensure the program included the correct time.h and used the correct `time`, I renamed the header to mytime.h and the `time` class to `mytime`. All errors went away (a few warnings about unused parameters remain) as soon as the potential for ambiguity was removed.

I recommend using something a little less banal than `mytime`, but feel free to use whatever you wish so long as the name is descriptive and there are no more collisions.